# git like commands in python

Tags: python, git, argparse

My goal is to have

- `myScript init` without more run the class/action `InitAction`.
- `myScript foo /tmp` run the class/action `FooAction` using the given "/tmp"

With argparse I made up this parser

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Look like GIT!")

parserCommands = parser.add_subparsers(title="Actions")

init_parser = parserCommands.add_argument('init', help='Set up')
destroy_parser = parserCommands.add_parser('destroy', help='Tear down')
```

Good till here but I want to bind `init` to the `InitAction(argparse.Action)`. Something that works like `action=InitAction` but unfortunately this isn't allowed there.

Do you have a clue how to run InitAction when writing `myScript.py init` in the terminal?

Answer (score 2):

The `argparse` documentation has an example of calling functions based on the subparser command

> 16.4.5.1. Sub-commands
>
> One particularly effective way of handling sub-commands is to combine the use of the add_subparsers() method with calls to set_defaults() so that each subparser knows which Python function it should execute. For example:

```
>>> # create the parser for the "foo" command
>>> parser_foo = subparsers.add_parser('foo')
>>> ...
>>> parser_foo.set_defaults(func=foo)
...
>>> # parse the args and call whatever function was selected
>>> args = parser.parse_args('foo 1 -x 2'.split())
>>> args.func(args)
```

Following that is an example using the 'dest':

> the dest keyword argument to the add_subparsers() call will work'

I don't think you want to subclass `argparse.Action`.  Normally an `Action` puts a value in the `args` namespace.  The 'init' string is actually a value that subparsers Action uses to pass control to the `init_parser`.  That's why your own Action class does not fit.  What you want is function that can be run after `parse_args` is done, and all it needs to use is `args`.